# Good articles to read on SSL and HTTPS?

Tags: security, ssl, https, certificate, ssl-certificate

I had a problem with accepting invalid SSL certificate in my iPhone program. That problem is solved now, however I came to understanding that I have very abstract idea on how exactly the whole thing is working:

- how web browser is verifying that received certificate is really for host it communicates to and not faked by same party in the middle?
- if browser talks to some 3rd party (CA?) to do certificate check?

and many other questions... 
Would someone please recommend good source of information with in-depth enough description of how all parts click together?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Plenty of detail here: [The First Few Milliseconds of an https Connection](http://www.moserware.com/2009/06/first-few-milliseconds-of-https.html)

And the definitive book on the subject: [SSL and TLS: Designing and Building Secure Systems](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201615983)

Comment: that blog post is amazing! real eye opener, no less.

Answer (score 1):

Check the [articles here](http://www.eldos.com/sbb/articles/65-184.php), specifically "Introduction to SSL" and "Building user authentication systems for client-server environments."

Answer (score 0):

[Web Spoofing  Revisited: SSL and Beyond](http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~pkilab/papers/tr417.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

This is an excellent BlakHat talk on modern attacks against SSL:
http://www.thoughtcrime.org/software/sslstrip/
Chrome recently introduced "Strict Transport Security"  for https which partially addresses Moxie Marlen Spikes attacks.